# Curl soap request using VPN linux

Tags: linux, curl, soap, vpn

I need to make a SOAP request using curl through VPN. The end point only allow call through VPN.

I have created a VPN and through it I am successfully able to hit the endpoint, But when I try to call it and send xml it returns me error

192.168.11.11 is my VPN

```
ssh root@192.168.11.11 curl \
--header "Content-Type:text/xml" \
--header "SOAPAction:GenericAPIRequest" \
--header "charset=UTF-8" \
--data "@call.xml" \
"http://10.xxx.xx.xx:8080/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxx"
```

call.xml is in the same directory from where I'm hitting curl request

It return me error "Warning: Couldn't read data from file "call.xml", this makes an empty POST."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This curl warning means that it could not `fopen` the file supplied.

The SSH command may be executing from root's home in `/root`, so ensure the file is there and that it is readable. You may want to use an absolute path.

Just to be clear, that curl command is executing on the remote side, so call.xml must be located on 192.168.11.11, and not in the directory on the client side where the ssh command is being executed from.